# How to import AIDL file in IntelliJ project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I have to edit an existing project created with another IDE and the direct import of the whole project doesn't work, so I have recreated the project copy pasting the various resources and setting the various libraries, I have also copied in the main root a folder named `aidl`that contains 2 aidl files.
The projec apparently compiles without any error unfortrunately when I try to run it I get a `ClassNotFoundException` that seems related to the aidl files that most probably are ignored during the make.

How can I link the aidl files to the project?

the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.vending.VendingApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.vending.VendingApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4529)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.vending.VendingApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4529)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.vending.VendingApplication
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Note that the project is a standard IntelliJ Application Moduler Project so I haven't any `build.gradle` file